# How can I customize the list of tables with the titletoc package?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I know how to customize the chapter and section toc with`titletoc` package, just like this:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{.1\baselineskip}\bfseries}
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace{2.8mm}}{}
    {\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```

But if I what to do this for `\listoftable` and `\listoffigure`, how to do?

What is the first parameter for that?

Comment: What do you mean? I think your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 8):

It's exactly the same, but using `figure` (or `table`) in the first mandatory argument of `\titlecontents`; here's a simple example just for illustration in which the number for figures in the LoF will appear framed and the leaders are formed with `$\cdot$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]{}
  {\fbox{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{1.5em}}
  {}{\ \titlerule*[8pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Another test caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]